# The wrapping machines of Santa

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Christmas is coming and Santa is working hard to wrap all the presents until the 24th of December.

> He has six wrapping machines: **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **E** and **F**, that work $24/7$ all at the same time. But the harsh weather of the North Pole keeps breaking the machines. Each machine has a panel that indicates the state of one or two other machines. However, if that machine is broken itself, the displayed information on its panel may not be true. However, if a machine is working properly, its panel displays valid information.
> The elves made a Main Control Panel so Santa can track all the six individual panels at once. On a certain day, Santa sees the this display on the Main Control:
>
> [image]
>
> **PROBLEM 01:**
> Given this display, is there any way of having just **one** broken machine?
>
> **PROBLEM 02:**
> If Santa has **two** broken machines, which ones are they?

This is an old puzzle from a book I had when I was a kid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PROBLEM 01

> I think this is not possible.
>  Consider just A and F in isolation.
>  If both are okay, then at least B and C are broken.
>  If A is okay, but F is broken, then C and F are broken.
>  If A is broken but F is okay then A and B are broken.
>  If both are broken then A and F are broken so we always have at least two broken machines.

PROBLEM 02

> In the four scenarios considered in PROBLEM 01, the only one which produces exactly two broken machines is when A and F are both okay, in which case **B** and **C** must be the broken machines.

Comment: That was fast! I swear to God, one day I will post a puzzle so hard you will need an entire month to solve it, LOL! That's it. I'm just waiting to accept your answer.

Answer (score 7):

A compact answer:

> A says C is broken.  So, one of A and C is broken.
>  F says B is broken.  So, one of B and F is broken.
>
>  It is clear from that that at least 2 machines are broken
>
>  If 2 machines are broken, they are among A, B, C, F.  So E is reliable.
>  E tells us that between A and C, C is the broken one, and between B and F it is B.
>
>  You can check that if only B and C are broken, all other pannels are correct.